# Single Sign-In For Multiple PHP Websites

Tags: php, single-sign-on

I am having four different php websites. First website is implemented in codeigniter, second one is implemented in core php, third and fourth websites are implemented in wordpress. All 4 websites are **having different logins**(user authentication).

Now i want to change user authentication for all my sites. **I want my users to use one single email-id and password for my 4 websites**. If user, login into any website, then he should be **able to automatically login into other 3 websites** without asking login again(similar to, with one google account, we can login into googleplus,youtube,maps,drive).

I can keep all my four php websites under one domain(using sub-domains). But i don't no how to achieve single sign-in for all 4 different websites.

**My big concern is, i am using 4 different databases for 4 websites. Every database is having its own "users table".  Now how can i integrate one login for all 4 websites**

I dont want to use "login through gmail or login through facebook". i want to have my own login system for all my websites

Can anyone suggest me, from where i should start?

Comment: Well, you can do 4 inserts at once

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use the SAML protocol to resolve your problem.

1. Create a simple database with a unique table, user data: mail, password. Dump over this database your users from the different 4 sites.
2. Deploy an IdP based on simpleSAMLphp and use  the database as authsource.
3. Deploy an SP per application using simpleSAMLphp and connect those SPs to your IdP.
4. In the integration between SP and your application make sure that you supporting SSO, SLO but also user provisioning.

And thats all, with this approach you can SSO applications that are in different domains and easily you gonna be able to add more apps in the future.

P.S If you need new users in your platform, create an small register app that let the user add a email and pass that will be stored in the database of the IdP. Other way is to decide that the registration will be done in one of your 4 applications, disable that functionality in the others and use that database as your auth source.

Other alternative if all your apps are in the same machine is to create a 5th app that has the credentials info of the the 4databases..
You need to locate in your 4 apps where is the logic of the user registration and before it, load the code of your 5th app and handle the registration at the rest of your apps.

For SSO is easy. Locate in the 4 apps where the login code logic is and before load the code that prompt the user/pass form, review if a global unique session exists, if exists, force the login in the app.   Notice that you gonna set this global session the first time that the user is logged in any of your app.

And that are my 2 $,  I prefer the 1st solution, more standard.

Answer (score 0):

ok its possible!

i would take me the wordpress database data, because i wouldnt't try to edit the wordpress authentification. You only must connect your other 2 websites with the wordpress-database and retrive the email an password. but you must show, because the wordpresspassword is an hash.

Good Luck!